# How can I retrieve a lost password from the Windows Vault?

Tags: windows-7, password-recovery, credentials-manager

Is there anyway I can get back a forgotten password that is remembered and stored in my Windows Vault on my Windows 7 Professional laptop?

Comment: What do you want to do with this password? Do you need to delete it (in case it was a wrong input) or you simply want to know it so that you can use it for other purposes.

Answer (score 14):

Perhaps it's worth trying [Network Password Decryptor](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Decrypting-Decoding/NetworkPasswordDecryptor.shtml)? It can apparently decrypt the passwords stored in the vault. I've not used it myself though.

[Edit]
If that doesn't work there is another program that does a similar thing: [Network Password Recovery v1.31](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/network_password_recovery.html) (just make sure you are logged in as an administrator *and* run it as an administrator)
[/Edit]

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: shows me my username and os but when i press button to start, just nothing happens, tried running as admin too but still the same.

Comment: Did you try the **Network Password Recovery** program in the end? Nirsoft's tools actually seem pretty good - I was using their BlueScreenViewer utility the other day.

Comment: The second link (Network Password Recovery) worked well for me.

Comment: Note that the Network Password Recovery installer installs some really dodgy looking crapware.